# Is this "about general computing hardware and software"?

Tags: discussion, flags, triage

Let's say I would have this in triage:
[How to Remove Gnome From Ubuntu 17.10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46611472/how-to-remove-gnome-from-ubuntu-17-10)

> I'm using Ubuntu 17.10 Beta but to be honest, I'm not a big fan of
>   gnome and So How can I Completely Install Another GUI / Desktop
>   Environment like Unity or Cinnamon but I don't happen to find up a
>   good tutorial on how to do that?
>
> Can you guys please help?
>
> Thanks!

would it be correct to mark it unsalvageable because it's about hardware and software?

It's a flagging option but it's not in the triage guidelines:
[How does the Triage queue work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295650/how-does-the-triage-queue-work)

Comment: I've updated [How does the Triage queue work?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/295650) to have a more complete list. Does that make the text there clear enough to cover your question?

Comment: Thanks ! That makes it clearer.